# angular SSR not showing child components data in page source

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am using angular 15 universal but in SSR mode I can not see child components (custom tags) content in page source

I try to add some static contents in child component and try to see that in source but can not see them again
I am passing data to child component like this

```
<app-single-activity [activity]="w4Activity"></app-single-activity>
```

but not showing activity data in page source
but the same data is showing in source when is in parent component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can not any body help me ?